# Проблемы с запуском Gradle-проекта: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'

Tags: java, spring, rest, gradle

При запуске Gradle-проекта выдает ошибку(Spring):

```java
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.3\jbr\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Проект делаю по следующему туториалу - https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/. Дошел до момента Hello World.

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```java
package com.example.demo.controllers;
import java.net.URI;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class Demo {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

```java
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.4.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Мало информации. По идее в логах ещё что то должнобыть